# How does the Dumang DK6 keyboard work?

Tags: microcontroller, keyboard

The Dumang DK6 keyboard is a modular mechanical keyboard, where each key is mounted into an independent saddle with its own microcontroller, and each saddle can be independently positioned anywhere on a magnetic, horizontally ribbed board.

Each saddle has 4 magnets in each of its 4 corners to adhere it to the board.

On the bottom of each saddle are 8 electrical contacts that appear to receive power from the board, while simultaneously handling keypresses and RGB data.  It appears that each key's 8 contacts make contact with 3 ribs.

It's difficult to describe, so here are some pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The website for this product is https://www.velocifiretech.com/products/dumang-dk6-ergo-v2?variant=39757815677046 if you want to get more information.

How is power, keypress signaling, and RGB data simultaneously achieved through the 8 contacts of each key making contact with 3 ribs, while each rib may come in contact with multiple keys?

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer how specifically the Dumang DK6 works. However, I can sketch how I would design one to meet the description, as a plausibility argument.

If each key contacts 3 consecutive conductive ribs, and if they are ordered in a consistent power, ground, data, power, ground, data order, then each key will always contact one of each, on at least one pin.

16 diodes, 8 up and 8 down off each pin will rectify power to the on-key MCU. If the data ribs have a reasonable resistance, then it will be trivial for the MCU to inject a test current into each of its key pins to identify which pins are which. Or the MCU could monitor all pins for activity, assuming the keyboard waggles the data line around from time to time.

Bidirectional data is then trivial to handle. Any rib has at most a dozen keys to multiplex. How fast can you type?

They might have missed a trick, in that it's possible to handle power and bidirectional communication with only two ribs types, by multiplexing the data onto the power rib, they could then use fewer contacts on the bottom of the key.